# Not sure why Spring aspects aren't triggering

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, spring-aspects

So I started digging into Spring AOP, and tried to create some basic aspect with annotations but it doesn't seem to trigger for some reason.

*This is my aspect:*

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class TestScribe {

    private Logger logger;

    @Autowired
    private LogHandler logHandler;

    @PostConstruct
    private void setup(){
        logger = logHandler.getLogger(LogType.TEST);
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* arbana.sneaky.racoon.utility.BasicStringOperationsTest.test_trimLastChar(..))")
    public void testStart(){}

    @Before("testStart()")
    public void markTest() {
        logger.info("Aspect happened!");
    }

}
```

When I set breakpoints on `setup()` and `markTest()` I can see that the *@PostConstruct* method `setup()` gets triggered, but the `markTest()` does not.

*This is my JUnit test case that I'm trying to pointcut:*

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"/arbana/sneaky/racoon/contexts/utility.xml"})
public class BasicStringOperationsTest {

    @Autowired
    private BasicStringOperations stringOperations;

    @Test
    public void test_trimLastChar() {
        assertEquals("trimme", stringOperations.trimLastChar("trimmed"));
    }

}
```

*And this is my bean configuration XML (testing.xml):*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    ">

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <import resource="classpath:/arbana/sneaky/racoon/contexts/handlers.xml"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="arbana.sneaky.racoon.test"/>

</beans>
```

The `handlers.xml` and `utility.xml` are pretty much the same except with different *base-package* parameter in the *component-scan*

Clearly I'm doing something wrong.
Any tips and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT :**

Ok so I tried to change the pointcut to:

```
execution(* arbana.sneaky.racoon.utility.BasicStringOperations.trimLastChar(..))
```

to target the actual method being tested rather than the JUnit test method, and apparently aspect works in that situation.

So now my assumption is that JUnit and Spring Aspects don't like each other.

Now I'm curious if there is some way around this.

Comment: your class BasicStringOperationsTest is not a spring bean, so spring can't create a proxy

Comment: Sounds reasonable, would you happen to know how to do this? I tried annotating it with @Component as well as manually defining it in the XML, but none of that seems to propagate the aspect regardless. :(

Comment: why would you need to use an aspect during testing? maybe there is a different path you could take.

Comment: My original intent was to log the execution of JUnits (test method names, execution times, possible exceptions thrown during execution, etc.) in a test log file via log4j2. So I thought `@Around` and `@AfterThrowing` would be able to do this quite elegantly.

Comment: The aspect in Spring only covers Spring beans it will create a proxy for those and as such intercept the methods. The JUnit test isn't a spring bean and will not be proxied. If you want to intercept those methods you will have to use a full blown AspectJ solution with either load or compile time weaving.